# What's wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

This is the first thing I write in javascript, so I hope its a basic error

What I'm trying to achieve here:
Take a bunch of links from a page, load their contents query for links inside and add them to a list on current page.

I get error on the append
And in JQ documentation they say the method can get a JQ object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var wtf = $(".download");
        var links = $("a", wtf)
        links.each(function (index) {
            var newFrame = document.createElement("div");
            $(newFrame).load($(this).context.href, function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    alert("error");
                }
                $("a", response).each(function (index) {
                    $("#results").append($(this));
                });
            });
            //  $("#results").append(newFrame);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with JavaScript as a language before taking on libraries such as jQuery. It'll be easier to pick up that way.

Comment: post please a screenshot or a better description of an error.

Comment: For one, the .load function requires a jQuery object to work. You have merely created a variable called newFrame with <pre>var newFrame</pre>
which isn't a jQuery object. So .load won't work on that.

Comment: @Muhammad - OP isn't doing `newFrame.load(...`. The new `div` element being wrapped in a jQuery object `$(newFrame).load(...`

Comment: You can create a new div and assign an ID to it - 'divname', for example. Then use $('#divname').load() ...

Comment: According to the jQuery API documentation "if the current document does not contain an element (...) the .load() method is not executed.". In your situation you create new element, but it is not attached to the document. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: after creating the object do i need to append it first to the page and than query for him?

Comment: Some information regarding the existing HTML layout would be useful. I don't know where this `#results` element is, nor do any of us understand the nature and goal of the application.

Comment: @Ventus - That means that if the jQuery object doesn't contain an element because the selector `#result` (from the example) didn't find a match, then `.load()` isn't called. In this case, the jQuery object contains the newly created `div`, so `.load()` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see if my <del>guessing</del> error checking abilities are good enough for this:

```
// No point really in using context here.
// This would be better, or at least more readable
var links = $(".download a");

// No need to add in the argument if you're not actually going to use it
links.each(function() {
    // Doing this will get you create the jQuery object
    // without having to use the DOM createElement method
    var newFrame = $('<div />');

    // this.href is shorter and neater
    newFrame.load(this.href, {
        'html': '.ajax'
    }, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            console.log(xhr);
        }

        // This is the odd part - response is a selector?
        // This should loop through each anchor that are a child
        // Of the element selected by the response receieved
        // Using appendTo here is better than looping through
        // each element and using .append() there
        $(response).find("a").appendTo("#results");

        // And finally of course because this is .load()
        // Remember that the actual response is also
        // appeneded to the element in question,
        // hence the extra .ajax appearing there
    });

    // This occures outside of callback,
    // so it's actually executed *before* the code above
    $("#results").append(newFrame);
});
```

See jsfiddle for this piece of code actually working: http://jsfiddle.net/E589q/4/

Comment: On first line, This will select all links inside the element that have the download class?

Comment: @Chen You mean a function that looks for elements beyond the first level of descendants, like `children()`? You should be using `find()` then. Also, as I've noted, these are hazy guesses to what you're trying to do. If you've got any other questions do feel free to ask another one.

Comment: @Chen Yes, that is true. If you only need one level the selector would look like `.download > a`

Answer (score 0):

the load function does not have error handling capabilities, it is meant for simple Ajax functionality only.

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 $(document).ready(
function () {

    var links = $("a.download")
    $.each(links,
    function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var newFrame = $("<div></div>").appendTo('body').css({position: 'absolute', top: '100px',  left: '100px'});
          $(newFrame).load(url)
              })
                            })

//-->
</script>
```